# I was trying to authenticate Google Sign-in to my android APP but the sign-in is not working

Tags: android, firebase

I was trying to authenticate Google Sign-in to my android APP but the sign-in is not working and i don't know why it is giving the error

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import com.example.social.databinding.ActivitySignInBinding
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInRequest
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.ktx.app
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_sign_in.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await

class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private val RC_SIGN_IN: Int = 123
        private val TAG = "SignInActivity Tag"
        private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
        private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)

            // Configure Google Sign In
            val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()
            googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
            auth = Firebase.auth

            binding.signInButton.setOnClickListener {
                signIn()
            }

        }

        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
            val currentUser = auth.currentUser
            updateUI(currentUser)
        }

        private fun signIn() {
            val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:")
        }

        @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                handleSignInResult(task)
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogleaayaaaya:")
            }
        }

        private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
            try {
                val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.id)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)

            }
        }

        @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
        private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
            val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
            binding.signInButton.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val auth = auth.signInWithCredential(credential).await()
                val user = auth.user
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    updateUI(user)
                }
            }

        }

        private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
            if(user != null) {
                val mainActivityIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(mainActivityIntent)
                finish()
            } else {
                binding.signInButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
```

while going throught the logcat i realised that

```
try {
                val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.id)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
}
```

this is not working , can anybody help

logcat is and also it is showing error that bufferItemConsumer : onDisconnect()
[logcat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG2KF.png)

Comment: "the sign-in is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have a crash? Besides that, since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help.

Comment: I mean to say that the app running without crash but after clicking on sign in button you can see in the log image that instead of running try function it is showing   catch function resulting in sign in is not happening means it is not going inside the try function  'try {
                val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.id)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)'

Comment: The screenshot doesn't provide an Exception message. Please take a better look,

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Actually the main error was before it was not mandatory to add SHC fingerprints but now it is necessary , so i did that and that worked for me